# Library for face recognition

Tags: python-3.x, face-recognition

How to install face_recognition package on python3.

I tried it by using,

```
pip install face_recognition
```

but not working when compiling .
On statement.

```
import face_recognition
```

The error is

> no module named face_recognition

Comment: Are you talking about [this](https://pypi.org/project/face_recognition/) package?

Comment: Try `pip3 install face_recognition`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi before installing face_recognition in python3 you have to install
    `dblib`,     `numpy`,     `opencv`

packages you can find it at,

```
https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/175#issue-257710508

https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

https://pypi.org/project/numpy/
```

Hope you got the answer.